# Sir Trevor JS in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, sirtrevor

I'm trying to import Sir Trevor JS library in my Angular 2 Typescript project. I tried to write a .d.ts file but the library is quite large and complex. Is there a way to do that? Thank you all.

Comment: unless the project is written in typescript you can't do it automatically. the alternative would be to just use declare x :any; to make the errors go away.. but you won't get any of the typescript goodies like automplete or types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the type inference and autocomplete features you will need either a .ts file with the code or a .d.ts file describing it.

Since Sir Trevor js is written in javascript there is no way to automatically generate the .d.ts file (there doesn't seem to be a .d.ts file on [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/) either).

You can however use **declare** to use it as you would be using it in javascript.

```js
declare var SirTrevor: any; // declared as any, so anything goes

new SirTrevor.Editor({el: someElement});
```

The resulting js will be:

```
new SirTrevor.Editor({ el: someElement });
```

Comment: @Samuele I wouldn't call it perfect but it's a decent enough workaround to integrate javascript code with typescript. :)